# convert BDP formula to tia

Tags: python, bloomberg

I am new to python.
I have a BDP formula like this =`BDP(bond, 'RTG_SP', "SETTLE_DT=20180426")` and trying to convert it to tia.

When I use `LocalTerminal.get_historical(bond, 'RTG_SP', start='20180426', end='20180426')`, I got nothing received.
Maybe I should use `LocalTerminal.get_reference()`, but I didn't see the param `SETTLE_DT`.
Is there a way to get the value from tia?

Thanks!

Comment: If this is some sort of proprietary API issue, you should check the API SDK documentation, post it here if you need others to help spot your syntax error.

Answer (score 0):

`RTG_SP` does not provide historical data directly. You need to use overrides:

```
In[1]: from xbbg import blp

In[2]: blp.bdp('XS1627599654 Corp', 'RTG_SP')
Out[2]:
              ticker   field value
0  XS1627599654 Corp  RTG_SP     B

In[3]: blp.bdp('XS1627599654 Corp', 'RTG_SP', Rating_As_Of_Date_override='20180201')
Out[3]:
              ticker   field value
0  USG4863AAC20 Corp  RTG_SP   BB+
```

Using [`xbbg`](https://xbbg.readthedocs.io) for demo